# How to trigger to re-creation of deployment without any command

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, deployment, kubernetes-helm

Apologies in advance, I am quite new to Kubernetes, we have some Helm charts that we use to implement monitoring stacks to various environments using Kubernetes. I am updating the helm charts versions and one version, in particular, requires deployment to be re-created.

I tried running

`kubectl delete deployment <deploymentname>`

and then implementing the update which works but I need a way to trigger deployment creation from values.yaml file so that it triggers in all of the environments we have when I run the pipeline instead of me going to all of them manually and deleting deployments beforehand.

I also tried adding an annotation like

```
annotations:
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt:
```

but that didn't work.

The error I am getting :

```
13:40:55  2023-02-22 13:40:55,354 - ERROR  -
Command 'kubectl --kubeconfig=/tmp/tmpxv384dq8 apply --validate=False
-f /tmp/tmp9ku4lg20' failed with: The Deployment "pgw-prometheus-pushgateway" 
is invalid: spec.selector: Invalid value:
v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"pgw",
"app.kubernetes.io/name":"prometheus-pushgateway"},
MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: field is immutable
```

Comment: do you see deployment object? you can check by running `kubectl get deploy -n <<namespace>>`

Comment: @YashJagdale yes there is a deployment object which is for the current version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically the solution I found was overriding the deployment name.
I added `fullnameOverride` value to values yaml file (this is provided in the helm charts values) and changed the name slightly from the previous and that deleted the old deployment and created the new one without me doing `kubectl delete deploy` beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a number of Kubernetes applications managed via Helm Charts and you want one of them to be "forced" restarted.

I guess this is your request, because it happens that if there are no "significant" changes to the values.yaml of your application, the Helm Upgrade command doesn’t trigger the re-deploy/deploy of the new version.

To make sure that the reboot occurs at each Upgrade command, you can modify the Deployment template by adding:

```
     annotations:
         rollme: {{ randAlphaNum 5 | quote }}
```

https://v3.helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments

Comment: Yes, you did understand it correctly. I did try what you suggested actually and then I get an error with Jenkins in the pipeline build stage that says Error converting YAML to JSON.

Comment: To exclude some variable... do a "helm upgrade" manually triggers the rollout restart even without changing anything?
Have you put the "annotation" in your Deployment template under spec/template/metadata?

Comment: No matter how I place it I get : `failed to parse values/prometheus-operator.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map`

Comment: What version of helm are you using? If less than 3, you can still use *--recreate-pods*

Comment: We're using v3.7.1

Comment: Ok, so i confirm that *--recreate-pods* still working for your version.